# How to switch Activities without killing them in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have this Activity1(Restaurant) which switch to Acticity2(Home)

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RestaurantActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish(); // Call once you redirect to another activity
```

My other Activity (Home) has a boolean to check if I have been at Home before

```
public static boolean visitedHomeAlready = true;

if(!visitedHomeAlready) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, RestaurantActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish(); //
}
```

My idea is: If I have not visited the home before and switch to Restaurant Activity, I want to "remember" the data in the Home Activity to continue my game after come back home but it always start from the beginning from my home...
I am not sure which flags I have to set or which method to resume that state from where exactly where I switch the activity.

Comment: Just remove the ```finish();``` line, that's the function call that kills the activity. Without it, you can return like normal. Not sure for the reason behind the boolean check once you fix that

Comment: Do I have to change something with the flag? I saw another post told something about `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);`

Comment: Assuming you launch into the Home activity, you shouldn't need to specify any flags. Once you enter the Restaurant activity from the Home activity then return to Home, Home will already have been running and doesn't call ```onCreate``` again, but calls ```onResume```. Take some time to skim through the [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle), you'll see switching to a new activity doesn't kill the current one unless you specify it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

As Amin commented above,the `finish();` means that the first activity has finished its job and the app will end it,if you removed it the second activity will start,but the first activity will still be in its place and you can go back to it just by clicking the back button on your phone or virtual device.